# What does "bombing" mean?

Tags: meaning

Of course I am not asking about the obvious meaning.

The context is like

> If you are afraid a few moments of quiet will make it look like you're
> "bombing" as a leader.....

Comment: This question's been closed. Hmm. So one might say it *bombed* as a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This most likely comes from the show business tradition, hence the quotation marks. There one who *bombs* or is *bombing* fails miserably to entertain the audience. Here your protagonist is afraid of failing badly at the job they are trying to do. American English is filled with the experience of failure described as bombing.

In American English a *bomb* is a failure while in German it is a great success. No symbolism please. In American English a great show or movie would be called a *blockbuster* which was a very large sort of bomb back in WWII.

Comment: Dictionaries provide an appropriate and helpful range of meanings.

Comment: *"In American English a bomb is a failure"* - Yes, *a* bomb is a failure, but *the* bomb is a success. (Just pointing out an exception; other than that I agree with your answer.)